# How do you foster collaboration between foundation/service and product engineering teams?

Tags: management, collaboration

Recently joined a company where the engineering teams are broken down by foundation teams and product engineering teams. The charter for the foundation team is to build products that are reusable by other product engineering teams. Think about things like email notifications for transactional emails, notifications for changes in the system the user subscribed for, search functionality, etc.

What I am seeing in this place is there are engineers in the product engineering who are controlling the discussion of how things are built by the foundation teams to the technology and how it should be packaged. IMO, that is outside the boundary of the product engineering teams and a responsibilities of the foundation teams.

Can you all share (Those who work in orgs with similar structure) on how you all decide on how the foundation and product engineering teams collaborate. How do you ensure decisions are made without deadlocks because of consensus paralysis. Do you have a set of goals you have defined that are part of each team.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace DLS. You state you recently joined such company. Are you in a position to decide on the collaboration policies and dynamics? Is there some documentation or existing policies/handbook that you can check and find out? Finally, mind enhancing on why you state that product should have no saying on the foundation team?

Answer (score 4):

> that is outside the boundary of the product engineering teams and a responsibilities of the foundation teams.

Treat it like any other requirements gathering process. The product team needs a component that does something. How this component can be accessed is *indeed* a requirement. Your .NET team might require a NuGet package. Your Angular team might require a npm package. Giving any of them a .jar file because the foundation team loves Java would not fulfill any of the requirements.

However, how these requirements are met, is in the hands of the foundation team and maybe some corporate guidelines. Anything that happens "behind" that interface requested as per the requirements in none of the product teams business. If the Nuget package and npm file just collect the parameters and then send them to a server hosted by the foundation team, written in Java? Sounds good. All requirements met.

Please note that *some* technical decisions *are* bound to non-functional requirements. If the product team requires the data to not be shipped outside their juristiction, you might not be able to use a cloud provider. If the product team requires a certain level of security, you might not be able to make certain decisions. Those are requirements, too. "Don't use the cloud" is not a valid requirement, that is one team intruding into another teams technical domain. "Don't save the data on servers outside our state" is a very valid legal requirement, though. You can still try to find a cloud provider who does it, but if you don't find any, you will have to change your technical approach.

So to summarize: product teams can have requirements, that might even be the technical details of the interface. It is the foundation team's job to make sure the requirements are met and it's their privilege to decide how to meet them.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the product engineering team is the "customer". It's pointless for the foundation team to build something that the customer doesn't want or can't use. That means the production team sets the requirements and priorities.

On the other hand, the whole idea of having a foundation team is to reuse work over multiple products/projects. In order for them to do that, they can (and indeed should) require the different product teams to agree on requirements and priorities. You can only reuse an e-mail notification system in different products if all products agree to use the same interface and feature set (maybe with a light weight wrapper around it).

It's the business's responsibility to facilitate this process. Ideally product teams submit requirements and feature request, the foundation team can scope them and the business decides which one's to work in which order and with what level of re-usability